# Charts.js en MVC.NET muestra Chart anterior al pasar ratón por encima

Tags: .net, chart.js

Tengo un problema a la hora de mostrar unos gráficos.

En función de unos combos Se carga un gráfico de barras, la primera vez lo hace correctamente, el problema llega cuando se cambian los combos y muestra el nuevo gráfico, que al pasar el ratón por encima muestra la gráfica que se cargó en primer momento.

El código en el que se monta el gráfico es este

```
window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: "bar",
            data: {
                labels: labels,
                datasets: [{
                    label: "Ocurrencia",
                    backgroundColor: Blue,
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    data: ocurrences
                }, {
                    label: "Impacto",
                    backgroundColor: "darkred",
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    data: impacts
                }]
            },
            options: {
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: chartName + "     " + effectivenessValue + "% Efectividad"
                },
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: true,
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: "Nº. Ocurrencias",
                            fontSize: "12"
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            callback: function (value) {
                                return Number(value).toFixed();
                            },
                            stepSize: 1,
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
```

he intentado borrar los datasets, el propio chart, el propio canvas, vaciar el div del canvas pero sigue ocurriendo.

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: He añadido algo de código donde se forma el gráfico

Comment: ¿Y el código donde se cambia el gráfico? En serio, antes de seguir pidiéndote de a una cosa que falta por vez, ¿podrías intentar publicar un ejemplo que sirva para ejecutar y poder ver el error que estás describiendo? Se espera que tu pregunta tenga un [mcve]. Te recomiendo leer ese artículo (el mismo que aparece en la notificación bajo tu pregunta)

Comment: Buenas. el código para formar los gráficos es el mismo tanto para generarlo como para actualizar.

Ya he encontrado el error,

Al tener que ser tan ad-hoc hay muchos métodos de generación de gráficos.

En algunos de ellos en vez de 

`window.myBar = new Chart()`

se utilizaba 

`window.myBar = new window.Chart()`


de forma que aunque hiciésemos `myBar.destroy()` obviamente nunca limpiaba los datos de aquellos gráficos que estaban generados como `new window.Chart()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema venía dado por unos gráficos que se estaban generando de la siguiente manera:

```
window.myBar = new window.Chart();
```

en vez de:

```
window.myBar = new Chart();
```

De forma que cuando hacíamos:

```
myBar.update();
```

y

```
myBar.destroy();
```

no se hacía en todas las gráficas.

Comment: felicitaciones :D eleva ese cosmos y sigue con todo el power 2.0!!! :D